# knitr: how to set package options depending on output type

Tags: r, knitr

I am starting to use package `knitr` as a component in the workflow to produce `HTML`and `PDF` reports from a `Markdown` input file.
I would like to set some `knitr` package options specifically tailored to the format of the output file.
Currently I manually switch back and forth the following two lines:

```
<!--roptions dev='png', fig.width=300px, fig.height=200px" -->
<!--roptions dev='pdf', fig.width=5, fig.height=4 -->
```

Is it possible to let knitr know which set of options to use based on output type, automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `pandoc` with `knitr` to produce html and pdf from the same `markdown` file. I will post an example shortly.

Comment: this is also what I started to do recently; you can make use of section 3.5 in the manual: https://github.com/downloads/yihui/knitr/knitr-manual.pdf (assign variables instead of fixed values to your chunk options), and I believe Ramnath can show you a good workflow. BTW, `fig.width=300px` is not valid; it always has to be numeric (unit in inches): http://yihui.name/knitr/options

Comment: Thank you Ramnath and @Yihui. I came up with a rather clumsy solution by letting knitr create the images in one of the two formats (let's say pdf). Then, in Makefile, convert all images to png (ImageMagick), search .pdf occurrences and replace them with .png in the knitted file (by sed), and finally pandoc it to html. This is the relevant part of Makefile I came up with: html:knit
 convert Rplots/*.pdf Rplots/*.png
 sed  's/.pdf/.png/g' $(DOCUMENTNAME).md > $(DOCUMENTNAME)-html.md
 pandoc -s --toc -c report.css $(DOCUMENTNAME)-html.md -o $(DOCUMENTNAME).html
 rm $(DOCUMENTNAME)-html.md

Comment: do you know that with the latest version of `knitr`, you can actually use a vector of devices? e.g. `dev=c('png','pdf')` so two formats will be created with one shot; `Makefile` should be a good way go to, but conversion from pdf to png may not be necessary; I also have another clumsy approach that I'm waiting for Ramnath to correct in https://github.com/yihui/knitr-book but you can see how I dealt with with different output formats

Comment: I have created a `github` repository that has a `source.md` file and a `makefile` that you can use to create `html` and `pdf` outputs. It is self-explanatory if you know `pandoc` and `makefiles`. I will a `README.md` when time permits :-). Here is the link to the repository https://github.com/ramnathv/knitr-pandoc

Comment: Thank you Ramnath, your `Makefile` enlightened me on setting options to knitr. I have solved my problem by setting `dev`, `fig.width`and `fig.height` before calling `knit`. BTW `-e "pat_gfm()"` did not work for me as `R`quits with a `pat_gfm function not found` message, is it still not supported in the stable branch of knitr?

Comment: Ramnath, if you care to answer the question, I will check it.

Comment: @Yihui, thanks for your efforts on `knitr` and your excellent feedback.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, `pat_gfm()` is in version 0.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ramnath comment suggests a [solution](https://github.com/ramnathv/knitr-pandoc) to producing `pdf` and `html` output from a unique `Markdown` file by setting specific options to `knitr`in the `Makefile`:

```
$(PDF): $(SRC) Makefile
Rscript \
  -e "library(knitr)" \
  -e "opts_chunk[['set']](dev = 'pdf')" \
  -e "pat_gfm()" \
  -e "knit('$<', 'temp.md')"
$(PANDOC) temp.md -o $@
rm temp.md
```

Here the format of images is set to `pdf`. Note that the `pat_gfm()` function has been added in the master branch on [GitHub](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/d11b96d0e4e464833725af34d42853fd9dd9d90c#R/pattern.R) just 5 days ago and has not been released as a stable version yet.

Elaborating a bit to fully answer the question, the image dimensions can be easily setted by adding a couple of lines to the Makefile:

```
-e "opts_chunk[['set']](fig.width = 5)"\
-e "opts_chunk[['set']](fig.height = 5)"\
```